# Can bean validation be documented with enunciate?

Tags: bean-validation, enunciate

Is there a way to have enunciate document bean validation rules?

Does it work for both bean validation by annotation and bean validation by xml configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate doesn't currently have support for enhancing documentation based on bean validation annotations.

Comment: Thank you for confirming